# Finding distinct values in column and adding another column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If I have a table with columns a and b as shown

```
a b
1 1
1 10
1 20
2 11
2 21
3 31
```

I want to insert into this table the distinct values in column a along with an arbitrary constant, let's say 0. So I want the output to be:

```
a b
1 1
1 10
1 20
2 11
2 21
3 31
1 0
2 0
3 0
```

How can I use `INSERT INTO` with `DISTINCT` to accomplish this? I'm not sure how to incorporate the arbitrary constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do what you said, INSERT SELECT DISTINCT:

```
insert into tablename select distinct a, 0 from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward:

```
insert into your_Table (a, b)
select distinct a, 0
from your_Table
```